# Latex Forest Package Reduce the length of lines betwen nodes?

Tags: nodes, forest, trees

By using Forest package i am try to create red-black tree. In some point in my presentation i need to shorten the lines between the nodes which are red, but the parents are black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={circle, draw, s sep=15pt, l sep=5pt, font=\tiny\color{white}\bfseries, minimum size=15pt},
        [, fill=black!80
            [, fill=black!80
                [, draw=none]
                [, draw=none]
            ]
            [, fill=red!80
                [, fill=black!80
                    [, fill=red!80
                        [, draw=none]
                        [, draw=none]
                    ]
                    [, fill=red!80
                        [, draw=none]
                        [, draw=none]
                    ]
                ]
                [, fill=black!80
                    [, draw=none]
                    [, fill=red!80
                        [, draw=none]
                        [, draw=none]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
\end{forest}
            
\end{document}
```

You can see the output generated by the code below.

[image: Figure 1]

After this step i am trying to do something like this.

Please ignore the style difference between figures. I am just try to shorten the length of the lines between red-black nodes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch Hi, I have organized the code to be compiled. What I am trying to do is to add the shortened version of the lines in the specified tree.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Nope this is not create the desired output.

Comment: Can you explain what you want your code to do? You say you want 'something like this' and then show 3 different trees. It looks like your current tree could be aimed at either the first or second of these target trees, but it isn't clear which you want and the third tree seems unrelated to the code you've given.

Comment: @cfr I am trying to create these three different trees. At this point i can create the first tree, but i couldn't generate the other trees. My main aim is reduce the length of lines between black (parent) and red (child) nodes. Only the black (parent) and red (child) nodes, if child is black it should not reduce the lengths. At the end i will produce four different tree with different line lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I've used the tree you coded as my example. The fourth tree has no red nodes so, since the question specifically concerns adjusting the distances between red children and black parents, there is nothing to do in this case.

So the question basically asks how to format one tree in three different ways. In the following code, `@+\rbtree` expands to the bracket specification of your tree modulo some tidying up with modified styles and such like.

```
\begin{forest}
  red black,
  @+\rbtree
\end{forest}
```

This produces the result shown in your question with minor modifications which get it a bit closer to what you want. This is the baseline/starting point.

```
\begin{forest}
  red black,
  squash,
  @+\rbtree
\end{forest}
```

This approximates the next tree. Red nodes are moved closer to black parents, but they are not allowed to overlap.

```
\begin{forest}
  red black,
  squash,
  not distinct,
  s adjust'=4,
  l short'=10pt,
  @+\rbtree
\end{forest}
```

This code shortens the distances, but uses non-default values for `s adjust` and `l short` so red children overlap each other and underlap their black parents. `not distinct` switches off drop shadows, disables code used to encourage node separation and alters the order in which the tree is drawn. Normally, trees are drawn top down, but we don't want that here, so we use `tree children-first` to draw the tree bottom up instead. This gets children to underlap parents rather than overlapping them.

[image: one tree three ways]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
% ateb : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707076/ addaswyd o gwestiwn İbrahim Uğur ABA: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706871/
\forestset{%
  declare boolean={red node}{0},
  declare boolean={black node}{0},
  declare boolean={squashed}{0},
  declare boolean register={squash},
  declare boolean register={distinct},
  not squash,
  distinct,
  declare dimen register={l short},
  declare count register={s adjust},
  l short'=15pt,
  s adjust'=5,
  red black/.style={%
    for tree={%
      fit=band,
      circle, 
      draw, 
      s sep'=15pt, 
      l'=5pt, 
      l sep'=5pt,
      edge+=thick,
      if n children=0{%
        inner sep=.5pt,
        fill,
        before computing xy={l'=12pt},
      }{%
        text=white,
        font=\tiny\sffamily\bfseries, 
        minimum size=15pt,
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      if squash={%
        for descendants={%
          if={ > OO& {red node}{!u.black node} }{%
            before computing xy={%
              l/.register=l short,
              if={ > OOw+P< {n} {!u.n children}{(##1+1)/2} }{%
                s/.process={ ORw2+Pw+d {n}{s adjust}{-##2*##1}{##1pt} }
              }{%
                s/.process={ ORw2+Pw+d {n}{s adjust}{##2*##1}{##1pt} }
              },
            },
          }{},
        },
        if distinct={%
          where black node={%
            tempcounta'=0,
            if nodewalk empty={filter={children}{>O{red node}}}{}{%
              for nodewalk={filter={children}{>O{red node}}}{%
                if={ > O_ > {n}{1} }{%
                  if={ > O {!p.red node} }{%
                    insert before={[,phantom]}
                  }{},
                }{},
              },
            },
          }{},
        }{%
          /tikz/circular drop shadow/.style={},
          draw tree processing order/.nodewalk style=tree children-first,
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
  red one/.style={fill=red,circular drop shadow,red node},
  black one/.style={fill=black,circular drop shadow,black node},
}
\bracketset{action character=@}
\NewDocumentCommand \rbtree {}{%
  [, black one
    [, black one
      []
      []
    ]
    [, red one
      [, black one
        [, red one
          []
          []
        ]
        [, red one
          []
          []
        ]
      ]
      [, black one
        []
        [, red one
          []
          []
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  red black,
  @+\rbtree
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  red black,
  squash,
  @+\rbtree
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  red black,
  squash,
  not distinct,
  s adjust'=4,
  l short'=10pt,
  @+\rbtree
\end{forest}
            
\end{document}
```

Note that the use of `\rbtree` is pure convenience. Unless you need the same content in multiple trees, you should ignore this and specify your trees in the usual way. It just avoids duplication since the first three trees have identical specifications.

Comment: This is my solution. Thank you for the information.